# Is there any performance difference for nested document in mongodb query

Tags: performance, mongodb, nested

If I create an index for username field, which document is better for query a specific user?

The nested one:

```
 {
        account:{
        username:'zhengyi',  
        passwd:'zhengyi',
        friends:[]
        }
        dev:{
            os:'iOS',
            ver:'6.0',
            hw:'iPhone2,1'
        },
        app:{
            ver:'1.0',
            pver:'1.0'
        }
    }
```

The unnested one:

```
  {    
        username:'zhengyi',
        passwd:'zhengyi',
        friends:[],
        dev:{
            os:'iOS',
            ver:'6.0',
            hw:'iPhone2,1'
        },
        app:{
            ver:'1.0',
            pver:'1.0'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't make a difference
You're either doing:

```
db.collection.findOne({"username":"zhengyi"});
```

or

```
db.collection.findOne({"account.username":"zhengyi"});
```

Read up on the [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) for embedded documents

Similarly, indexes use the dot notation to reach inside a document:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"username": 1});
```

Or

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"account.username": 1});
```