# MongoDB Collection Structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection named User.

User has many information that can be grouped together example:

```
{address : {street:"xx", city:"xx"}}
{history: {school:"xx", job: "xx"}}
{..}
```

So I want to know what the best practice is

```
1. First way, Using nested fields:

{user: 
  {address : {street:"xx", city:"xx"}}
  {history: {school:"xx", job: "xx"}}
  {..}
}

2. Second way: Just put them all together.

    {user: 
      street:"xx", 
      city:"xx",
      ...
      school:"xx", 
      job: "xx",
      ...
    }
```

First way is obviously more readable for humans and it makes it easier for human to find relevant information.

What are the downside to grouping/nesting data like the first way?
Does it make querying of nested fields slower? Indexing issues? Any idea?

Comment: mongodb is not OODB, so it is not designed to store objects, even though it is possible. what benefit do you get from storing "address" as an object that contains street and city? it would be much easier to store it the 2nd way, flatten, so queries can be simpler.

Comment: i guess it's more readable the first way. Information can be grouped accordingly, reading relevant data is easier.  But is there any performance downside?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any performance difference for nested document in mongodb query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395188/is-there-any-performance-difference-for-nested-document-in-mongodb-query)

Comment: Right, yes i want to confirm the answer was no difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you store the extra data under the user, it enables faster reading and writing of entire user document.

If you the extra data under separate collections, it may enable faster access find/update of that data (depending on your indexes). MongoDB does enable [indexing fields in arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index)

My suggestion is to try and list your common data access use cases, create a test database with a LOT of mock data, then test performances using queries and aggregations to defer between the different storage modelling options.

Comment: So the first way i mentioned in my question, does not involve using separate collections nor array.  I just structure it as a nested fields. Would this make queries/indexing for those fields that are nested?

Comment: @user1955934 Not sure what you meant in your comment, however, querying is possible on nested info, less straightforward though. Also, I highly recommend you check out the aggregation API. Also, don't forget the explain option on queries.